# ticpp traverse nodes in reverse order

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, iterator

I'm using ticpp to have an easy manner to handle xml-files. However the iterator interface is a bit awkward to use.. Am I correct in assuming there is no way to traverse the children of a certain parent in reverse order? ([documentation](http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/docs/classticpp_1_1Iterator.html))

The iterator interface does have a `operator--()`. However calling this upon the "end" iterator results in a "Access violation reading location 0x00000000.". Am I missing something? Is there a fast way to handle this?

The solution I'm thinking of currently is to simply traverse the list twice: first storing all children in a `std::array` (array is best here?).. And then again check all elements in reverse order. But as said: I can't help but think I must've missed some function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turned out there was something I missed; instead of using the iterator interface supplied by ticpp, I could also use the node-based interface from tixml. (ticpp being just an abstraction layer).

Few functions allowed for the following loop:

```
for(ticpp::Node* pchild(elem.LastChild()); 
    pchild != nullptr; 
    pchild = pchild->PreviousSibling(false)) {
```